# Update logic based on json data in c# asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

I have a sample `JSON` data which is as below. What I want to do with below JSON is. IF response below coming has 2 things like

IF `success` is `true` and `ParentList.length > 0` then `(logic of updation in C#)`

```html
{
    "success": "true",
    "Building_rjid": "NVMBBD0015609",
    "ParentList": [
        {
            "Site_sap_id": "I-MU-MUMB-ENB-I134",
            "Site_GeoCoordinates": "19.01612,73.04158",
            "Site_priority": "P1",
            "BearingAngleFromBuilding": 278
        },
        {
            "Site_sap_id": "I-MU-MUMB-ENB-7172",
            "Site_GeoCoordinates": "19.0138,73.041",
            "Site_priority": "P2",
            "BearingAngleFromBuilding": 205
        },
        {
            "Site_sap_id": "I-MU-MUMB-ENB-7202",
            "Site_GeoCoordinates": "19.01841417,73.043785",
            "Site_priority": "P3",
            "BearingAngleFromBuilding": 33
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is how I bring JSON response

```
try
        {
            strInputJSON_BldgRJID = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(inputBldgRJID);

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            jsonData = client.UploadString(apiUrl_CheckBldg, strInputJSON_BldgRJID); // json response
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could understand, you want to do something like this:

```
public class ModelX
{
    [JsonPropertyName("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("Building_rjid")]
    public bool BuildingRjId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("ParentList")]
    public List<ParentList> ParentList { get; set; }

}
```

```
public class ParentList
{
    // TODO
}
```

```
public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jsonString = "{\r\n    \"success\": \"true\",\r\n    \"Building_rjid\": \"NVMBBD0015609\",\r\n    \"ParentList\": [\r\n        {\r\n            \"Site_sap_id\": \"I-MU-MUMB-ENB-I134\",\r\n            \"Site_GeoCoordinates\": \"19.01612,73.04158\",\r\n            \"Site_priority\": \"P1\",\r\n            \"BearingAngleFromBuilding\": 278\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n            \"Site_sap_id\": \"I-MU-MUMB-ENB-7172\",\r\n            \"Site_GeoCoordinates\": \"19.0138,73.041\",\r\n            \"Site_priority\": \"P2\",\r\n            \"BearingAngleFromBuilding\": 205\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n            \"Site_sap_id\": \"I-MU-MUMB-ENB-7202\",\r\n            \"Site_GeoCoordinates\": \"19.01841417,73.043785\",\r\n            \"Site_priority\": \"P3\",\r\n            \"BearingAngleFromBuilding\": 33\r\n        }\r\n    ]\r\n}";
        
        var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ModelX>(jsonString);

        if (model != null && model.Success && model.ParentList.Count > 0)
        {
            // TODO
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error on `JsonPropertyName` as could not be found (are you missing a using....)

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio automatically imports this "using System.Text.Json.Serialization;". And for JsonSerializer you need to import "using System.Text.Json;". Which version of dotnet are you using?

Comment: I am using VS 2013

Comment: thanks vdschuck, need one more help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77297760/display-data-based-on-json-parameter-in-c-sharp-asp-net